# window.Location not updated on button click in tests for jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

Wanted to verify that the window.location gets updated on user click in my jest react test.
But window.location doesn't seem to capture the change.

Following is my current setup:-

jest-environment.js - custom environment file

```
const JSDOMEnvironment = require('jest-environment-jsdom');
module.exports = class JSDOMEnvironmentGlobal extends JSDOMEnvironment {
  constructor(config) {
    super(config);
    this.global.jsdom = this.dom;
  }

  teardown() {
    this.global.jsdom = null;

    return super.teardown();
  }

  runScript(script) {
    return super.runScript(script);
  }
};
```

jest-config.js

```
"testEnvironment": "./jest-environment",
```

My jest test:

```
describe('verifying links', () => {
        const { getByText } = render(WithTestRouter(<Component />));
        const Elemen1Link = getByText('Elemen1');
        global.jsdom.reconfigure({
          url: 'https://www.google.com/',
        });

        fireEvent.click(Elemen1Link);

        expect(window.location.pathname).toEqual('/element1');
      });
```

RESULT:
(window.location.pathname is always `/`.

NOTE: Typescript complains about `Property 'jsdom' does not exist on type 'Global'.`

Do I have to also add location to the global variable in jest-environment.js file?